# Global Vector Direction from Local Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

**Unknown 3D Vector Direction**

Let $\vec{v}=(x,y,z)$ be an unknown 3D vector in global coordinates. We want to determine its direction (ignoring magnitude) based on the following information:

**Planes:**

- **Plane A:**

  - The equation in global coordinates: $A^xx+A^yy+A^z​z=D^A$
  - A Known projection vector on this plane having $d=(d^u,d^v)$ in local U, V coordinates.
- **Plane B:**
- The equation in global coordinates: $B^xx+B^yy+B^z​z=E^A$

  - A Known projection vector on this plane having $e=(e^u​,e^v)$ in local U, V coordinates.

**How can I Find the direction of v (ignoring magnitude).**

**TEST DATA:**

Plane 01:   $1.96x + 0.34y + 1z = 0$

Plane 02:   $-0.3x  + 0.23y + 1z = 0$

3D vector = $0.62,-0.196,1$
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf7sv.jpg)